# Why I am index error while writing a segmentation code using Unet?

Tags: python, pytorch, segmentation-fault

Highlighted the part from where I am getting the error.Getting the error from resize_image_with_crop_or_pad

```
class CreateDataset(data.Dataset):
    
  def __init__(self,          
                filePath # path to the data files location
                ):
    
    # Define the DataloaderClass main variables
    self.filePath = filePath
    self.dataset = None
    self.datasetLen = 0
    
    # get the number of slices in the 3D image as the dataset length
    with h5py.File(self.filePath, 'r') as fl:
      self.datasetLen = fl['image'].shape[2]
    
  # This function returns the dataset from the h5 file to 
  # the Pytorch Dataloader function
  def __getitem__(self, 
                  idx):
    
    # Read the h5 file into the dataset variable
    self.dataset = h5py.File(self.filePath, 'r')
    #print(self.filePaths[self.index])
    
    # load the images data into numpy array 
    self.images = np.asarray(self.dataset['image'])
    self.labels = np.asarray(self.dataset['label'])
    
**    # resize/crop the 3D images to (112,112,80) size
    self.images = resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(self.images, (112,112,80))
    self.labels = resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(self.labels, (112,112,80))**
    
    # extend the dimensions to get one item of the 3D image
    self.image = torch.from_numpy(np.expand_dims(self.images, axis=0))
    self.label = torch.from_numpy(np.expand_dims(self.labels, axis=0))
    
    return self.image, self.label

  # This function returns the size of the input data
  def __len__(self):
    return self.datasetLen

# This function iterates over all the h5 files to get the complete dataset
# For each h5 file the CreateDataset class is initiated
def createDatasetFunction(filepath, mode):
  
    # Load the file locations of the h5 files
    filepaths = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath, '*.h5')))
    datasets = []
    
    for path in filepaths:
        try:
            logger.info(f'Loading {mode} set from: {path}...')
            dataset = CreateDataset(path)
            datasets.append(dataset)
        except Exception:
            logger.error('error')
    
    return datasets
  
# This function resizes/crops the 3D images
**def resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, img_size=(64, 64, 64), **kwargs):
    """Image resizing. Resizes image by cropping or padding dimension
     to fit specified size.
    Args:
        image (np.ndarray): image to be resized
        img_size (list or tuple): new image size
        kwargs (): additional arguments to be passed to np.pad
    Returns:
        np.ndarray: resized image
    """

    assert isinstance(image, (np.ndarray, np.generic))
    assert (image.ndim - 1 == len(img_size) or image.ndim == len(img_size)), \
        'Example size doesnt fit image size'

    # Get the image dimensionality
    rank = len(img_size)

    # Create placeholders for the new shape
    from_indices = [[0, image.shape[dim]] for dim in range(rank)]
    to_padding = [[0, 0] for dim in range(rank)]

    slicer = [slice(None)] * rank

    # For each dimensions find whether it is supposed to be cropped or padded
    for i in range(rank):
        if image.shape[i] < img_size[i]:
            to_padding[i][0] = (img_size[i] - image.shape[i]) // 2
            to_padding[i][1] = img_size[i] - image.shape[i] - to_padding[i][0]
        else:
            from_indices[i][0] = int(np.floor((image.shape[i] - img_size[i]) / 2.))
            from_indices[i][1] = from_indices[i][0] + img_size[i]

        # Create slicer object to crop or leave each dimension
        slicer[i] = slice(from_indices[i][0], from_indices[i][1])

    # Pad the cropped image to extend the missing dimension
    return np.pad(image[slicer], to_padding, **kwargs)**
```

Error details:

```
IndexError: Caught IndexError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
data = fetcher.fetch(index)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py", line 243, in __getitem__
return self.datasets[dataset_idx][sample_idx]
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Assignment-xiao/problem2_data_new/dataLoad.py", line 43, in __getitem__
self.images = resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(self.images, (112,112,80))
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Assignment-xiao/problem2_data_new/dataLoad.py", line 112, in resize_image_with_crop_or_pad
return np.pad(image[slicer], to_padding, **kwargs)
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: the first step in debugging this, imo, is to `print()` or log `slicer` to see why `np.pad` is objecting to its type.